# multiple form actions in html page?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

i currently worked with is code...i must insert data into a table in oracle databse 10g and the table name is REGISTER ..so i made register.html page like this and put the jsp file according to it and created validation page too ...wer do i add validation page in????

```html
<html>
<head>
<center>
<marquee><h1>WELCOME FOR REGISTRATION</h1></marquee></center>
</head>
<body bgcolor=aqua>
<center>
<font size=8>
<form action="./register.jsp">
<img src="images/Register_Now.gif" width="200" height="60" ><br><br>
<tr>
<td><label>First Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="Enter first Name" value=""><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Last Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" value=""><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Contact:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Enter contact" value=""><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Address:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Enter address" value=""><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Gender:</label></td>
<td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" checked="checked">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<label><strong>
Type Of User</strong></td><td><select name="user" >
<option value="technician">TECHNICIAN</option>
<option value="supervisor">SUPERVISOR</option>
<option value="client">CLIENT</option>
</select></td>
</strong>
</label><br><br></tr>
<tr>
<td><label>State:</label></td> <td><select name="state">
<option value="Default">Select a State</option>
<optgroup label="INDIA">
<option value="karnataka">karnataka</option>
<option value="Telangana">Telangana</option>
<option value="Uttar Pradesh">Uttar Pradesh</option>
</optgroup></td>
</select><br><br></tr>
<tr>
<td><label>City:</label></td> <td><select name="city">
<option value="Default">Select a City</option>
<optgroup label="Andhra Pradesh">
<option value="Kakinada">Kakinada</option>
<option value="Vishakhapatnam">Vizag</option>
<option value="Vijaywada">Vijaywada</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Uttar Pradesh">
<option value="Mathura">Mathura</option>
<option value="Varanasi">Varanasi</option>
<option value="Lucknow">Lucknow</option>
</optgroup>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>EmailID:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="emailid" placeholder="Enter Email Here"><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Password:</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password Here"><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Confirm Password:</label></td>
<td><input type="password" name="password1" placeholder="Enter password here"><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label>Date Of Birth</label></td>
<td><input type="date" name="dob" placeholder="Enter date" value=""><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><strong><i>captcha</i></strong></label>&emsp;</td><td><img src="CaptchaServlet"><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label><strong><i>Enter captcha </i></strong></label></td><td><input type="text" name="code"><br><br></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" value="Register"></td>
<td><input type="reset" value="Refresh"></td>
</tr>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and the jsp file goes like

```js
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" session="true"%>
<%!
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;
String a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k;
int l,m;
%>

<%
a=request.getParameter("fname");
b=request.getParameter("lname");
c=request.getParameter("address");
d=request.getParameter("gender");
e=request.getParameter("user");
f=request.getParameter("state");
g=request.getParameter("city");
h=request.getParameter("emailid");
i=request.getParameter("password");
j=request.getParameter("password1");
k=request.getParameter("code");
l=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("contact"));
m=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dob"));
session.setAttribute("aa",a);
session.setAttribute("bb",b);
session.setAttribute("cc",c);
session.setAttribute("dd",d);
session.setAttribute("ee",e);
session.setAttribute("ff",f);
session.setAttribute("gg",g);
session.setAttribute("hh",h);
session.setAttribute("ii",i);
session.setAttribute("jj",k);
session.setAttribute("ll",l);
session.setAttribute("mm",m);

try
{
 Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
 con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root");
 
    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into register values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1,h);
ps.setString(2,a);
ps.setString(3,b);
ps.setString(4,l);
ps.setString(5,c);
ps.setString(6,d);
ps.setString(7,f);
ps.setString(8,g);
ps.setString(9,i);
ps.setString(10,m);
ps.setString(11,e);
ps.execute();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both validation and registration functions, I suggest you to use PHP. You can do it all in one or at the same page of `register.html` to make your work easy with `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`!

I can code php for you :-)

Comment: no brooo...actually im usin cmpletely jsp n html fa dis one..im stuck tht data is not storin in database soo jss i made it here ... once hlp me wud dat n ill put u d validation.jsp file olso

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery for validation. It validates the information on the client side, so you need not redirect to the next page unless the entered information is valid.